# Will Windows 10 IoT Mobile Enterprise utilize Isolated Storage?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

Our current application runs in Windows Mobile 6 and at certain points in the application life cycle a call is made to a .dll to show a usercontrol.  This .dll is specific to that project and is often updated independently of the application.  I've read that Windows Phone utilizes isolated storage that would make swapping out .dlls impossible.

What about Windows 10 IoT Mobile Enterprise.  Will storage be more open to allow that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not. You should really update your app to utilize the new Universal application framework - updating the DLL without the app is just not a good idea as there are not easy tools to do that. You can leverage the MDM protocol to automatically update your app without any user interaction.

[Universal app framework info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/whats-a-uwp?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: That's too bad.  This isn't my application.  It's a third party app that was designed to use reflection to load a .dll extension at run time giving us more flexibility to create custom screens for specific project use cases.